# How to split a string inside a list in Python?

Tags: python, string

How can I convert this:

```
['3 5 20']
```

to this:

```
['3', '5', '20']
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Not sure using a snippet was really useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input = ['3 5 20']
output = input[0].split()
```

Comment: `split()` is strictly equivalent to `split(' ')`. And `list` is redundant, since `split()` already returns a list. Your second line could just be `output = input[0].split()`.

Comment: @Efferalgan: `split()` is **not** strictly equivalent to `split(' ')`. To cite the docs: "[If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator ...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)"

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = ['3 5 20']
>>> [x for s in L for x in s.split()]
['3', '5', '20']
```

This will work for lists containing one or more strings.

Comment: This looks like overkill when `L[0].split()` could have done the trick.

Comment: @Efferalgan Well he gave answer which works for longer `list` , if he provide simpler answer then OP would again ask one more question on how to do the same to longer `list`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = ['3 5 20']
>>> l[0].split()
['3', '5', '20']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .split() function. It will return a list from a string.

Inside the brackets can be an argument which is what it looks for to split the string. If the brackets are empty it will be a default of spaces `(' ')`.

For example:

```
>>>l = ["Hi my name is Bon"]
>>>l = l[0].split()
>>>print(l)
['Hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Bon']
```

You can see in the example, it breaks the string by the spaces. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To combine list of such strings, using map and reduce:

```
required_list = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,  map(lambda x: str.split(x), ['3 5 20', '1 2 3']))
```

Required list will be:

```
['3', '5', '20', '1', '2', '3']
```